# How to handle session expire in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm building app in Swift-UI which follows MVVM architecture. I have implemented login flow like this

```
struct ApplicationSwitcher: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var user: UserDataVM

    var body: some View {
        if user.isLogedIn {
            HomeView()
        } else {
            LoginView()
        }
    }
}
```

where `isLogedIn` is variable of type `@Published`. The flow works fine.
But the problem is while handling **session expire**, I need to handle it in each API call and update `isLogedIn` EnvironmentObject in View. Is there any way that I can make this thing can be handled in common place so that I can avoid writing same code for all API calls.

Comment: I believe you have generic api calling code at 1 place... check there if 401, make this variable as false and reload app saying "Your session has been expired. Please login again to continue."

Comment: @FahimParkar The point is how can I reload App?

Comment: Dependency injection can handle this especially if the all use REST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a centralized authentication service that manages the user's login state and session expiry, this class can be called in the `NetworkManger` class

The `AuthenticationService` is where you would call the service to get a fresh token or maybe check the validity of the existing token and then publish results using the `isLoggedIn` published property.

```
final class AuthenticationService: ObservableObject {
@Published var isLoggedIn: Bool = false

func checkTokenValidity() {
 if 
//the token is valid then set the isLoggedIn to true
    isLoggedIn = true
else
  isLoggedIn = false
}

func fetchNewToken() {
    // once you get the token
  isLoggedIn = true
 }
}
```

Assuming that the `NetworkManager` is a class where you have `URLSession code`, you can check if the user `isLoggedIn` before you make the request and if not then use cancellable to cancel the tasks

You can pass the `AuthenticationService` as a dependency into the Network manager class that you have

```
final class NetworkService {
    let authenticationService: AuthenticationService

    init(authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
        self.authenticationService = authenticationService
    }

    func get() {
        if authenticationService.isLoggedIn {
            // Proceed with the API request
        } else {
            // Handle cancellation of the request
        }
    }
}
```

By integrating the `AuthenticationService` into your network layer, you can ensure that the user's login state is checked before every API request.

This should centralize the handling of session expiration and avoids the need to repeat the code in every API call.

To receive the isLoggedIn in a ViewModel or a View you can use the EnvironmentObject because you just need that one property to determine if you want to display the home view or the login view in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can Manage session expire using Your Api Reasonse. like How You can this code

**Step 1:**

in ViewModel Init one Variable Like

```
 @Published var isSessionEnd: Bool
    
    init(){
        self.isSessionEnd = false
    }
```

by default isSessionEnd is False.

**Step 2:**
set value in your api reasons like when  api reasonse message is "Your session is Exprire" then you can set isSessionEnd Value is true like this

just for Understand

```
 func apireasonse(){
        
        // just Example for mesage
        if apireasonsemesssage = "session ended "{
            self.isSessionEnd = true
        }
        else{
            //manage your reasonse here
        }
    }
```

**step 3:**
in View you can set when isSessioEnd is true then show Login Screen
here you can set this using ZSTack and also using NavigationLink both Code show below

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: HomeViewViewModel
    
    init(){
        viewModel = HomeViewViewModel()
    }
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            //            =============
            //            Conent
            //            =============
            
            if viewModel.isSessionEnd {
                //                LoginView()    // here Show Login Screen
            }
            /// OR
            NavigationLink(destination: LoginView(), isActive: $viewModel.isSessionEnd, label: { // destination: LoginView()
                EmptyView()
            })
            
            
        }
    }
}
```

if you have session expire with Fixed time then. in ViewModel to check current time with SessionExpireTime if condition to comapre to time if less then than Good and if equal or greeter than  then isSessionEnd is true set

Thank you
if You have any Down than Free to tell me @YouKnowBKA in telegram

Comment: Problem is there are multiple APIs, View and ViewModel. Every time API call is made I have to check for session expire and update State variable in the view. Instead of implementing this for every API call, can I write code such way that session expiry is handle in single point. So that I don't need write the same code every time.

Comment: can You explain me How to session Expire work?
means this is Fixed amount of time or Which Api call after in response to check ?

Comment: In Every API I will get session expire detail. If session expires, I have to navigate to login screen. As explained by in step 2. I hope you got it.

Comment: So you need to check every api if sessionexpire then show loginview == true and in view you can show login screen

Comment: exactly. I need to check in all api calls